# Java SSL/TLS Version Setting

Tags: java, ssl

Since Java 7 by default uses TLS 1.0, I would like to upgrade it to TLS1.2 for security enhancement [https only]. From oracle site (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html), 
it tells me I can simply do either of the following:

`java.lang.System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");`

OR

`java -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"`

Both of the methods work pretty well.

But I would like to ask why do I need to specify all TLS version here. How does this differs from

`java -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2"`?

Is specifying all TLS version allows to communicate with different servers which uses different TLS version?
In addition, does the order matters here? What if it is

`java -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1,TLSv1.1"`?

Will the behavior be different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is right. When you specify

```
java -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2"
```

you will be able to communicate only with clients which support TLSv1.2.

But when you have a list there

```
java -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1,TLSv1.1"
```

You will have a higher chance to be able to communicate with multiple clients which support those different versions. What is important to know is that **the strongest version supported by both will be chosen** during the handshake negotiation. (so the order in which  you defined them is not important)

Comment: s/clients/servers/g